# Recommendation System (R) for multiple items in a group

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to build a recommendation system where if a group of items have been selected, how do I get an item recommendation for that group (using R). The item does **not** have any ratings.

For example, in Amazon, if a person has multiple items in their basket, how would I recommend an item in consideration to all the items in the basket (including unrated items)

I have done item-to-item collaborative filtering, but that is based on a recommendation for individual Items. I am unsure of where to start for multiple item recommendation system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @FI_2018, sorry for opening an old topic. I'm trying to do the same system you mentioned for the academic project. Did you have any hints on what's the best approach?

Comment: Hey @Bart, I ended up using Market Basket Analysis (Association Rules). This allowed me to select the top 3-5 recommendations but without having the need of reviews and/or ratings. I did however change to PYTHON instead of R. Not sure how to do Market Basket Analysis on R.

Answer (score 0):

Every Matrix Factorization approach takes the whole history of a user into account not just a single item (as you are basically working with User-Item-Vectors). This history could also only be the "current" shopping cart.

The main problem you are facing is that you do not have Item Ratings (e.g., 5 Star Ranking). This problem called "implicit Feedback" is often solved using ranking-based Matrix Factorization approaches like BPR. I'm unsure if there is already an R implementation but there are plenty of Python packages (e.g., https://takuti.me/note/flurs/)